# Grouping views from different Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some controllers that have somethings in common, as such I want to group their views in a single folder structure. Something like this.

```
    Controller
              /Reservations
              /Logement
              /Suites
              /SuiteCategories
    View
        /hotel
              /Reservations
                           /Index
                           /Edit
                           /Delete
              /Logement
                          /Index
                           /Edit
                           /Delete
              /Suites
                           /Index
                           /Edit
                           /Delete
```

I registered this to the route engine without any result.

```
       routes.MapRoute(
          name: "hotels",
          url: "hotels/SuiteCategory/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "SuiteCategory", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Routing is not related to how ASP.NET MVC locates the views. Maybe you need an area?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları, thanks. If I were to use an area, could you please just describe how it will suite the need? I'm quite new with ms mvc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an area here. Areas are useful for grouping controllers with related functionality. They have their own folders with a similar structure to an MVC project. You already get a custom route and a folder just as you like when [you create an area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: from what I've read about area, it will not achieve the design.

Comment: @Wale Try to create one. If you are too strict about your design you can try something else. This is the supported way in ASP.NET MVC for project organization.

Comment: I've found a way around it without using an area. I added a route and make it the topmost. `routes.MapRoute(
             name: "hotels",
             url: "hotels/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "SuiteCategory", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );` And this works just fine.

Comment: @Wale You should post it as an answer so others can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way around it without using an area. I added a route and make it the topmost.

```
   routes.MapRoute( name: "hotels", 
                    url: "hotels/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                    defaults: new { controller = "SuiteCategory", 
                    action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

And this works just fine.

Comment: what if I then have one more folder like this: 
hotels/folder1/folder2/folder3/Index I know this will not work. Could there be any work around?